# JSON data and put in a array

Tags: arrays, json, angular

i have a file JSON (export from google sheet), here's my json:

```
{
    "Invités": {
        "Boizard ": {
        "Noms": "Boizard ",
        "Enfants": null,
        "FP": true,
        "Adresse": null,
        "Brunch": 7,
        "Nbr FP": 2,
        "OK": null,
        "OK enfant": null,
        "KO": null,
        "Attente": null,
        "mail cadeau": null,
        "Remerciements": null
        },
        "JLV et Sylviane Chartier": {
        "Noms": "JLV et Sylviane Chartier",
        "Enfants": null,
        "FP": true,
        "Adresse": "16 av du Général de Gaulle - 94300 Vincennes",
        "Brunch": 0,
        "Nbr FP": 1,
        "OK": null,
        "OK enfant": null,
        "KO": null,
        "Attente": null,
        "mail cadeau": null,
        "Remerciements": null
        },
        "J.........": {
        ..........
        ..........
        ..........
        }

    }   
}
```

i want to retrieve the data JSON from the file and the put in the array for  display them with angular

thx

Comment: OK. So, what have you tried? What's the concrete problem you're facing? What's your question?

Comment: use httpClient Module to read the file

Comment: thx for ur answer.
i placed the file JSON in folder asset.
I tried to recup the data with:

http://prntscr.com/oj91n0

here is the result:
http://prntscr.com/oj91tr

but i can not recup data with ngFor

Answer (score 0):

A very simple thing you can do is to include this file in your angular application as mock data so you can export it as a const (or create a `class` first) and then you can use it.
Or if you have a get method for this file you can create a service and `subscribe()` to it in order to put it in an array.

**UPDATE**

```
export class MyData {
  title: string;
  details: Details;
}

export class Details{
  ...
  Noms: string;
  Brunch: number;
  Enfants:..... ;
  ...
}

export const MYDATA: MyData[] = [
 {
   title: ...
   details: { ....
   }
 },
 {
   title: ...
   details: { ....
  }
 }, 
......
];
```

And use the *ngFor within MYDATA constant

Comment: i place the file JSON in the folde (asset), but i can not recup with ngFor

Comment: I updated my answer...take a look. I hope it will help you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, for cons I have a question, classes I create components for each? or I put in my TS file of my component that I use currently (sorry I start on Angular)

Comment: create a new .ts file and put it all together (the two classes and the constant)...then import them in the component you want in order to use it

Comment: Sorry, but I can not understand what you want to tell me ...
I have the impression that my problem comes from the fact that I can not exploit the data JSON in array

Answer (score 0):

Since you have got the data you can put them it to a *ngFor. Make sure you use invites.Invités since you have the array inside the Invités in json

Comment: it is precisely this part where I can not reach.
I think the problem comes from the JSON file

Comment: you can put {{invites | json}} to show the json value in the view for testing purposes. Check where it is displaying properly.

Comment: After testing, I think the problem comes from the ngFor
Here is what I have on my TS file:
http://prntscr.com/oj9tga
And my ngFor
http://prntscr.com/oj9tke

I try * ngFor = "let invite of invitees"

Comment: I guess the problem you have is in json response is coming with a tag "Invités". Try to use this.invites = data.Invités; in ts file